# Unique constraint violation found on "catalog_product_entity_tier_price"

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, tierprice

**Unique constraint violation found on "catalog_product_entity_tier_price".**

**Magento version 2.2.6:**

I have migrated data Magento1 to Magento2, i but some how **catalog_product_entity_tier_price** for this table constraint violation issue found.

```
query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `percentage_value`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /var/www/html/magento2/gsp/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php:580, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '65-0-7-1.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `percentage_value`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) at /var/www/html/magento2/gsp/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 23000): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '65-0-7-1.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087' at /var/www/html/magento2/gsp/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

**CASE 1**: I have set Tire price in Magento2 for all different customer Group, When I insert this entry it will violate my entry

**CASE 2**: For delete process not work properly

**File : vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Update.php**

This exception will comes with this file

Comment: I have the same problem .. Did you find a solution? Do you work with the API to push a product? What does ```select * from catalog_product_entity_tier_price where entity_id = 65``` show?

Comment: @Alex have you migrated database ?

Comment: Yes we did migrate the database with `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: No @Alex i mean to say have your project migrated Magento1 to Magento2 ?

Comment: No it's just a Magento 2 project

Comment: Did you solve your problem? In my cache I am temporarily able to solve it by clearing the cache ... but after while, the problem appears again, see https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277627/possible-bug-in-and-handling-of-getorigdata-when-updating-tier-prices-goes-away

Comment: the issue is facing for duplication. please check with tier prices, in database have already exist or delete data.

Comment: I had the same issue and i deleted all the advance pricing for test it and that worked.

Comment: @Divyesh : have you found solution about above error? Actualy i am facing same error.