# Possible bug in and handling of getOrigData when updating tier prices, goes away when cleaning the cache

Tags: tierprice, debugging, magento2.2.8

We are on Magento 2.2.8 and I was debugging the following issue for hours:

When sending a product-update via the REST API, we were getting

```
Unique constraint violation found
```

for a request as simple as

PUT https://www.example.de/rest/german/V1/products/B1234

Request body:

```
{"product": {"sku": "B1234","customAttributes": [{"attributeCode": "meta_keyword","value": "Bälle"}]}}}
```

The big problem is, that I cannot reproduce it using the Production Database Dump locally.

It seems to be strongly related to products which have a tier price in the database (which I am not updating in the REST call).

Luckily I was able to reproduce it somehow on a staging instance on the same machine as production and trace there error down to

```
vendor/magento/module- catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/UpdateHandler.php
```

[There is the following code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2.8/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/UpdateHandler.php#L86)

```
        // prepare original data to compare
        $origPrices = $entity->getOrigData($attribute->getName());
        $old = $this->prepareOldTierPriceToCompare($origPrices);
        // prepare data for save
        $new = $this->prepareNewDataForSave($priceRows, $isGlobal);

        $delete = array_diff_key($old, $new);
        $insert = array_diff_key($new, $old);
        $update = array_intersect_key($new, $old);
```

Using `var_dump`-driven development techniques I was able to see, that 
`$old` is empty even there IS a database row for the tier price.

Actually the whole `getOrigData()` is empty.

That causes having `$insert` a value which IS already in the database

So MySQL (MariadB) throws an error at the following insertValues call, which tries to insert the already existing value.

```
        $isAttributeChanged = $this->deleteValues($productId, $delete);
        $isAttributeChanged |= $this->insertValues($productId, $insert);
        $isAttributeChanged |= $this->updateValues($update, $old);
```

This is the error:

```
 "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '19211-1-0-10.0000-0' for key 'UNQ_E8AB433B9ACB00343ABB312AD2FAB087', query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` (`entity_id`, `all_groups`, `customer_group_id`, `qty`, `value`, `percentage_value`, `website_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

Now the interesting part: If I clean the Magento cache, the problem disappears. For a while. But after another while seems to / might happen again.

Did anybody see such behavior before? Should we just refactor the core to not be so dependent on getOrigData?

*EDIT* The bug can be reproduced after some time again. Clearing the cache then fixes it. For now I stored the redis cache in a backup and will try to reproduce the issue locally by loading that cache.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: @Oleksiy nope, not really. Not sure if it still happens in recent Magento versions. Which version are you on and how well can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Yes, it's really floating issue which reproduced only on one product. Magento 2.3.3. I have changed code https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/UpdateHandler.php#L99-L103 to this from new vesion https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Backend/TierPrice/UpdateHandler.php#L99 and it works for me.